# Anonymous user object in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm using the basic user login/logout system provided with Symfony and it works fine as long as people log in.  In that case the $user object is always provided as needed.

The problem is then when logged out (or not lgged in yet) there is no user object.  Is there a possibility to have (in that case) a default user object provided with my own default values?

Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: can you provide some sample code

Comment: Hi @Gordon, I tried the suggestion below but no succes :-(

Comment: Try to put `anonymous: ~` into your security.yml

Comment: That's already in it... @Gordon

Comment: It seems that the logoutAction() isn't even visited.

Comment: Can you give us some sample of your `security.yml`

Answer (score 3):

Because the solution mention above by @Chopchop (thanks anyway for your effort) didn't work here I wrote a little workaround.

I created a new class called myController which extends Controller.  The only function i override is the getUser() function.  There I implement it like this:

```
public function getUser()
{
    $user = Controller::getUser();

    if ( !is_object($user) )            
    {
        $user = new \ACME\myBundle\Entity\User();

        $user->setUserLASTNAME ('RaRa');
        $user->setID (0);
        // etc...
    }

    return $user;
}
```

This works fine for me now.  The only problem is that you really have to be careful NOT to forget to replace Controller by myController in all your *Controller.php files.  So, better suggestions still welcome.

Comment: Try with an authentication listener instead

Comment: Just read the documentation.  Seems to be a good alternative/solution.  Thanks @Gordon

Answer (score 3):

**Works in Symfony 3.3**

Using the suggestion of @Sfblaauw, I came up with a solution that uses a `CompilerPass`.

*AppBundle/AppBundle.php*

```
class AppBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        parent::build($container);
        $container->addCompilerPass(new OverrideAnonymousUserCompilerPass());
    }
}
```

*OverrideAnonymousUserCompilerPass.php*

```
class OverrideAnonymousCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $definition = $container->getDefinition('security.authentication.listener.anonymous');
        $definition->setClass(AnonymousAuthenticationListener::class);
    }
}
```

*AnonymousAuthenticationListener.php*

```
class AnonymousAuthenticationListener implements ListenerInterface
{
    private $tokenStorage;
    private $secret;
    private $authenticationManager;
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage, $secret, LoggerInterface $logger = null, AuthenticationManagerInterface $authenticationManager = null)
    {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
        $this->secret = $secret;
        $this->authenticationManager = $authenticationManager;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function handle(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        if (null !== $this->tokenStorage->getToken()) {
            return;
        }

        try {
            // This is the important line:
            $token = new AnonymousToken($this->secret, new AnonymousUser(), array());
            if (null !== $this->authenticationManager) {
                $token = $this->authenticationManager->authenticate($token);
            }

            $this->tokenStorage->setToken($token);

            if (null !== $this->logger) {
                $this->logger->info('Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token.');
            }
        } catch (AuthenticationException $failed) {
            if (null !== $this->logger) {
                $this->logger->info('Anonymous authentication failed.', array('exception' => $failed));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This file is a copy of the AnonymousAuthenticationListener that comes with Symfony, but with the `AnonymousToken` constructor changed to pass in an `AnonymousUser` class instead of a string. In my case, `AnonymousUser` is a class that extends my `User` object, but you can implement it however you like.

These changes mean that `{{ app.user }}` in Twig and `UserInterface` injections in PHP will always return a `User`: you can use `isinstance` to tell if it's an `AnonymousUser`, or add a method `isLoggedIn` to your `User` class which returns `true` in `User` but `false` in `AnonymousUser`.

Answer (score 0):

you can redirect the user not authenticated and force a fake login (to create a user ANONYMOUS)

and set it as well on logout

```
public function logoutAction(){

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $user = $em->getRepository('VendorBundle:User')->findByUserName('annonymous');

    $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
    $session->set('user', $user);
}
```

and if user is not set

```
public function checkLoginAction(){
    if(!$session->get('user')){
         $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
         $user = $em->getRepository('VendorBundle:User')->findByUserName('annonymous');
         $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
         $session->set('user', $user);
    }
    //this->redirect('/');
}
```

in you security.yml

```
security:
    firewalls:           
        main:
            access_denied_url: /check_login/

access_control:
        - { path: ^/$, role: ROLE_USER }
```

This is only an example i haven't tested (and will probably don't, since i don't get the purpose of doing this:) )

Comment: I need this because ALL my existing logic in this project (which I'am converting to Symfony now) needs a user id. (and i don't want to test everywhere like '$id = ($user) ? $user->getID() : 0;'

Comment: Does not work @chopchop.  my logs keeps on saying: Populated SecurityContext with an anonymous Token

Comment: have you seen this link ? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775852/symfony-2-receiving-anonymous-token-after-basic-authentication

Comment: I changed the answer. Instead of setting a temp user, you can fetch one from DB called anonymous

Comment: Using an fixed anonymous DB user isn't an option for me because each anonymous user is registered as a real user (without personal details) to track all the actions.  Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

**Using Symfony 2.6**

Like Gordon says use the authentication listener to override the default anonymous user.
Now you can add the properties that you need to the anonymous user, in my case the language and the currency.

*security.yml*

```
parameters:
    security.authentication.listener.anonymous.class: AppBundle\Security\Http\Firewall\AnonymousAuthenticationListener
```

*AnonymousAuthenticationListener.php*

```
namespace AppBundle\Security\Http\Firewall;

...
use AppBundle\Security\User\AnonymousUser;

class AnonymousAuthenticationListener implements ListenerInterface
{
    ...

    public function handle(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        ...

        try {
            $token = new AnonymousToken($this->key, new AnonymousUser(), array());
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

*AnonymousUser.php*

```
class AnonymousUser implements UserInterface
{
    public function getUsername() { return 'anon.'; }
}
```

Comment: Will this approach still work in Symfony 3.1? In particular, the parameter "security.authentication.listener.anonymous.class" which you are overriding dosn't even seem to existing anywhere else?

The original service definition in dynamic-files/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/Resources/config/security_listeners.xml looks like this:

`<service id="security.authentication.listener.anonymous" class="Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\AnonymousAuthenticationListener" public="false">`

Comment: Hi @Sam, this example does not work with Symfony 3. The parameter "security.authentication.listener.anonymous.class" does not exists any more. For example you can use the Compiler Pass to owerride the service class.